# Listing line number of results in `find` and `ls`

Tags: bash, find, ls

Is it possible with either `find` or `ls` to see, in a list of results, if any given entry is the nth result, what n is?

So, for example, pretend `ls -l` returns:

```
total 0
-rw-rw---- 1 bigdog bigdog 0 Jan  3 17:13 a
-rw-rw---- 1 bigdog bigdog 0 Jan  3 17:13 b
-rw-rw---- 1 bigdog bigdog 0 Jan  3 17:13 c
```

Is there a way to get `ls` to return 1,2,3 for files a,b,c respectively?

Or, `find . -type f` returns:

```
./a
./b
./c
```

Any way to get something like:

```
1 ./a
2 ./b
3 ./c
```

I am aware of `ls  | wc -l` and the like, but that is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: eh, same solution, but somewhat different problem

Comment: Not if you see the problem for what it is: "Run some command and get line numbers in output"

Comment: but how would i go about finding that thread given my question, ie how did you find it?

Comment: [Googled `line number output site:unix.stackexchange.com`](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?q=site%3Aunix.stackexchange.com%20line%20number%20output) (it was the last result on the first page.) The Stack Exchange site search is notoriously bad, Googling with a site restriction often yields better results.

Comment: eh ok, i'll accept that

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
ls | nl
```

Comment: Thx. Can't upvote but what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5):

"cat -n" will add line numbers. E.g.:
ls | cat -n

Comment: what i'm looking for, thx. probably could find this but my google query was awkward, i think.